# Apply phpunit.xml setting for speific classes only

Tags: laravel, phpunit

I have the following setting in my `phpunit.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="./vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit.xsd"
         bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php"
         colors="true">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Application Test Suite">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
    <coverage processUncoveredFiles="true">
        <include>
            <directory suffix=".php">./app</directory>
        </include>
    </coverage>
    <php>
        <env name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
        <env name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <env name="DB_CONNECTION" value="sqlite"/>
        <env name="DB_DATABASE" value=":memory:"/>
    </php>
</phpunit>
```

How can i tell to phpunit to use `:memory:` for certain test class and not for all classes ?

Comment: You can't do that... what you should be able to do is change the `env` before the `setUp` is run (when the database is migrated), but I would avoid t hat 100%, why would you need to swtich the database? It makes no sense at all... Either use Docker with the database services you need and connect to those. How is your code working and you need to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, PHPUnit is now unable to use custom environments for only some test suites. So you can't use the following code:

```xml
    ...
    <testsuite name="Application Test Suite">
        <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests</directory>
        <php>
            <env name="DB_DATABASE" value="example_db"/>
        </php>
    </testsuite>
    ...
```

So instead of setting the env `DB_DATABASE` via the `phpunit.xml` file, you can set it via the new `.env` file. Suppose you create a `.env.first` file that contains:

```
DB_DATABASE=first_db
```

Then in the `phpunit.xml` file, you can create a new `<testsuite>` which you will later target to use with the `.env` file you have created. As an example:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="./vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit.xsd"
         bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php"
         colors="true">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Foo">
            <directory prefix="FirstDB" suffix="Test.php">./tests</directory> <!-- Will match all files in `./tests` whose filename contains a FirstDB prefix and a Test.php suffix -->
        </testsuite>
        <testsuite name="Bar">
            <directory prefix="SecondDB" suffix="Test.php">./tests</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
    <coverage processUncoveredFiles="true">
        <include>
            <directory suffix=".php">./app</directory>
        </include>
    </coverage>
    <php>
        <env name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
        <env name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <env name="DB_CONNECTION" value="sqlite"/>
        <env name="DB_DATABASE" value="second_db"/>
    </php>
</phpunit>
```

Then for the next step you can run it with:

1. `php artisan test --env=first --testsuite=Foo`
2. `php artisan test --testsuite=Bar`